# How to translate page title's value using Angular Translate?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am translating my app into different languages using [Angular Translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) and if I have no problem translating elements in my page, I do not understand how to translates elements that belong to a value.

Exemple, the header of a ionic page :

```
<ion-view view-title="PROFILE">
```

Obviously, writing `<ion-view view-title="translate="HEADER_ACCOUNT"">`is not possible.

What would be the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate it like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="{{'PROFILE' | translate}}">
```

documentation here: https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/04_using-translate-filter

Comment: Thank you very much, for some reason, didn't find that one in the docs ! Let's say I am tired.

Comment: Glad to help :) @FrenchyNYC